# Generate a seemingly random array with no repeats, where each index has a larger and larger range of possible values

Tags: python, encryption, random

I have been toying around with using:

```
p = 4241 #Any large prime
x = 10 #Any Number smaller than p
 for i in range (x):
    print(p* (i) % 100)
```

To generate a seemingly random list of numbers. And while I would prefer if the list was more random, this is still adequate for my purposes. Onto my actual problem, I am trying to create a function that has 2 inputs

```
generate_i_in_sequence(i, seed)
```

Where I would be the index of the former array, and the seed would be something to randomize the result. The important part is that no two i's with the same seed generate the same output. This is simple enough, the other part is that the range of which I could be needs to be range(1,100+i) for example. A seemingly random number where the range of what that number could be grows as I grows. I would also prefer if the process is reversible. Basically a cipher.

I was expecting to be able to solve the problem with some clever solution of "steps" using the modulo expression. i = no_of_steps, and needed to linearly increase the range so:

```
PRIME* (i) % (x+(i))
```

However, because the range increasing also causes adverse effects to the sequence, it no longer generates i's with unique corresponding values, so I am not sure this is the way to go about the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Numpy Library to create your number like this:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_i_in_sequence(i,seed):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed+i)
    num = rng.integers(1, 100+i ,endpoint=True)
    return num
```

The seed being a set seed+i makes it so it is unique for every number ensuring every number generated by the function is different and reversible, even though the user only has to memorize one seed.

this function will return a number that is seemingly randomly generated, and then you can just append it to the end of your list to create your decrypted list

If you need more info feel free to ask, or check Numpy documentation for this [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.integers.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, unless I am misunderstanding, the numbers generated will appear multiple times for different values of i, for example, in the first 10 values of i, with seed 0, both 2 and 6 appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the numbers do not repeat by using non-overlapping ranges for each number. If, say, the allowed range is 100 possible numbers, each new number has the range `[previousNum+1 .. previousNum+99]`. The first number can be [0 .. 99] or [1 .. 100] depending if you want 0 allowed or not. If the first number generated is, say, 42 then the range for the second number is [43 .. 142] and so on.

As each number is generated, reset the range ready for the next number. With a given seed, the numbers will be generated in the same order so the allowed ranges will be the same as well.